# class modules in asp.net file system website

Tags: asp.net

I have a class module in my App_code folder.

```
Private _connection As MySqlConnection
Private _connStr As String

Public Function Connect(dbName As String) As Boolean
    Try
        _connStr = "Database=" & dbName & ";" & _
                "Data Source=192.16.0.1;" & _
                "User Id=user;Password=pass"
        _connection = New MySqlConnection(_connStr)
        _connection.Open()
        _connection.Close()
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        _connection = Nothing
        Return False
    End Try
    Return False
End Function
```

I usually program in webform apps. Why can't I access this function from my aspx code behind pages? I added the import statement for the class. If i make that function shared I cant have those private variables.

I call the function in my aspx lik so;

`If Connect(dbName) then....`

That gets me an error "non shared member requires an object reference"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the keyword "Shared" to the method signature, like so:

```
Private Shared _connection As MySqlConnection
Private Shared _connStr As String
Public Shared Function Connect(dbName As String) As Boolean
```

This is because otherwise you have instance class members, not static members. The compiler error message is quite self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

if you look at this example works:

```
   Public Shared Function example123(ByVal USER As Integer, ByVal Section As String,   ByVal ACTION As String) As Boolean
```

you assign a function **shared** so you can see it from outside the class

I hope you work